# input-validation-error class not added to custom HtmlHelper Extension Method

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I wrote my own HtmlHelper Extension Method to display a time-input.

```
public static MvcHtmlString TimePickerFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
        {
            if (expression == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");
            }

            string expressionText = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
            string value = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData).Model.ToString();
            return TimePicker(htmlHelper, expressionText, value);
        }

        public static MvcHtmlString TimePicker(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, string value)
        {
            TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("input");
            builder.MergeAttribute("type", "time");
            builder.MergeAttribute("id", name);
            builder.MergeAttribute("name", name);

            if (value != null)
            {
                builder.MergeAttribute("value", value);
            }

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
        }
```

This is how I use it:

```
@Html.TimePickerFor(model => model.StartTime)
```

When the time is not valid, I add an error like this:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("StartTime", "The selected time is already taken.");
```

When this error is added, it should add the `input-validation-error` class to the input, but it doesn't. I cannot get it to work. It does show the error in the `ValidationSummary`, and it adds the class to the default inputs. Any help would be appreciated!

I already tried adding it like this, but this still won't add the class:

```
var validation = helper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(name);
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Object> attribute in validation)
{
    builder.MergeAttribute(attribute.Key, attribute.Value.ToString());
}
```

**Edit:** temporary workaround found, haven't been able to solve the problem though

```
ModelState modelState;
if (helper.ViewData.ModelState.TryGetValue(name, out modelState))
{
    if (modelState.Errors.Count > 0)
         builder.AddCssClass("input-validation-error");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is not a workaround! that is how you are supposed to do it

```
string fullName = helper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name);
ModelState modelState;
if (helper.ViewData.ModelState.TryGetValue(fullName, out modelState))
{
    if (modelState.Errors.Count > 0)
    {
        builder.AddCssClass(HtmlHelper.ValidationInputCssClassName);
    }
}
```

The purpose of `GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes` is to return the attributes for unobtrusive validation to work. These attributes start with the name "data-val" and is used by `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="Please supply the title." id="Title" name="Title" type="time">
```

Your custom helper must have both in order to work properly.

For reference, read the source code of InputExtensions [here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/InputExtensions.cs)

**BUT wait!**

HTML5 time input is actually natively supported by MVC! You don't need to write your own.

```
public class TestModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime MyTime { get; set; }
}

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyTime)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that's quite a coincidence haha! I wrote it myself by putting together some scripts I found. I used the DataType.Time, however some things weren't working out for me for dates and times. I wasn't able to set a default date or min/max dates if I remember correctly. Thanks for your help and the useful source code.